# How to dispute Google Play Content Rating Change?

Tags: google-play-services, google-play

Recently, I received a mail from Google Play Support Team:

> This is a notification that the minimum content level of your application, *x*, with package ID *y*, has been changed to Medium Maturity (3) by the Google Play Team after a regular review.
>
> REASON FOR CONTENT LEVEL CHANGE: Violation of the Google Play content rating policy.
>
> After a regular review, we have determined that your app includes gambling themes. The content rating of your app has been changed to reflect this content.
>
> Please be advised that additional content rating modifications by the Google Play Team may result in administrative action, up to and including removal of subsequent applications in violation.
>
> All violations are tracked. Serious or repeated violations of any nature will result in the termination of your developer account, and investigation and possible termination of related Google accounts.
>
> We appreciate your contributions towards ensuring an accurate content rating experience for Google Play users.
>
> The Google Play Team

The problem with this mail is that my app is a fitness app where no currency transaction, virtual or real, takes place.
I would like to dispute the unfair content rating given to my app and the unfair threat given to me.

Could any one please help me find an appropriate forum or email where I can forward my dispute?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the link I used for a similar email :

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2992033?hl=en&ref_topic=3453554

I have not yet gotten an answer.

Comment: I got the answer which explains why the rating in my case got changed :We reviewed your app and chose to increase the content rating primarily due to ads that are being displayed. As stated in our Developer Program Policies in the Ad Policy section:
Ads are considered part of your app for purposes of content review and compliance with the Developer Terms. Therefore all of the policies referenced above also apply. Please take care to use advertising which does not violate the Developer Terms.

Ads which are inconsistent with the app’s content rating also violate our Developer Terms.